# Create an infinitely zooming image

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, gif, zoom

I found a website that almost does what I want gif-in-gif.com , but you can't adjust very much on the website. [I created a gif on it](http://gif-in-gif.com/images/1598071560-5832188.gif), but I want the zoom to happen on the eye of the baby, I want the gif to be bigger, and I want the zooming to be slower

Comment: Not sure what the actual question is, but I understand what you want to achieve. You could make something like this manually in Photoshop, but if you are not familiar with it, it might take some fiddling to get it right. gif-in-gif.com doesn't seem to offer any way to slow down the animation or make a bigger image. Zooming in on the eye could be achieved by changing the canvas size of the image so the eye is in the center and then maybe crop the resulting gif afterwards if needed (but that would also make the result even smaller).

Comment: @Wolff Go tip on the canvas size thing. I could probably use a tool like ffmpeg to change the speed of it. I don't know if I can fix the size thing though

Comment: @Wolff How would you do it with photoshop?

Comment: Well, that is a long story. If that is what you want to know, you should edit your question to ask specifically for that. And ideally also add some info on what you have tried and why you are stuck to give some sense of your skill level. As it is now your question doesn't really contain a question. No question mark to be seen .

Comment: I know how to program and can use iMovie and affinity designer and photo

Comment: Link's dead....